# Why is a MAX query with an equality filter on one other column so slow in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I'm running into an issue in PostgreSQL (version 9.6.10) with indexes not working to speed up a MAX query with a simple equality filter on another column. Logically it seems that a simple multicolumn index on `(A, B DESC)` should make the query super fast.

I can't for the life of me figure out why I can't get a query to be performant regardless of what indexes are defined.

The table definition has the following:
 - A primary key `foo VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY` (not used in the query)
 - A UUID field that is NOT NULL called `bar UUID`
 - A `sequential_id` column that was created as a `BIGSERIAL UNIQUE` type

Here's what the relevant columns look like exactly (with names modified for privacy):

```
                                             Table "public.foo"
        Column        |           Type           |                                   Modifiers
----------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 foo_uid            | character varying        | not null
 bar_uid            | uuid                     | not null
 sequential_id      | bigint                   | not null default nextval('foo_sequential_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "foo_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (foo_uid)
    "foo_bar_uid_sequential_id_idx", btree (bar_uid, sequential_id DESC)
    "foo_sequential_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (sequential_id)
```

Despite having the index listed above on `(bar_uid, sequential_id DESC)`, the following query requires an index scan and takes 100-300ms with a few million rows in the database.

The Query (get the max `sequential_id` for a given `bar_uid`):

```
SELECT MAX(sequential_id) 
FROM foo 
WHERE bar_uid = 'fa61424d-389f-4e75-ba2d-b77e6bb8491f';
```

The `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` result doesn't use the proper index. Also, for some reason it checks if `sequential_id IS NOT NULL` even though it's declared as `not null`.

```
                                                                                             QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=0.75..0.76 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=321.110..321.110 rows=1 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..0.75 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=321.106..321.106 rows=1 loops=1)
           ->  Index Scan Backward using foo_sequential_id_key on foo  (cost=0.43..98936.43 rows=308401 width=8) (actual time=321.106..321.106 rows=1 loops=1)
                 Index Cond: (sequential_id IS NOT NULL)
                 Filter: (bar_uid = 'fa61424d-389f-4e75-ba2d-b77e6bb8491f'::uuid)
                 Rows Removed by Filter: 920761
 Planning time: 0.196 ms
 Execution time: 321.127 ms
(9 rows)
```

I can add a seemingly unnecessary `GROUP BY` to this query, and that speeds it up a bit, but it's still really slow for a query that should be near instantaneous with indexes defined:

```
SELECT MAX(sequential_id) 
FROM foo 
WHERE bar_uid = 'fa61424d-389f-4e75-ba2d-b77e6bb8491f'
GROUP BY bar_uid;
```

The `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` result:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GroupAggregate  (cost=8510.54..65953.61 rows=6 width=24) (actual time=234.529..234.530 rows=1 loops=1)
   Group Key: bar_uid
   Buffers: shared hit=1 read=11909
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on foo  (cost=8510.54..64411.55 rows=308401 width=24) (actual time=65.259..201.969 rows=309023 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (bar_uid = 'fa61424d-389f-4e75-ba2d-b77e6bb8491f'::uuid)
         Heap Blocks: exact=10385
         Buffers: shared hit=1 read=11909
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on foo_bar_uid_sequential_id_idx  (cost=0.00..8433.43 rows=308401 width=0) (actual time=63.549..63.549 rows=309023 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (bar_uid = 'fa61424d-389f-4e75-ba2d-b77e6bb8491f'::uuid)
               Buffers: shared read=1525
 Planning time: 3.067 ms
 Execution time: 234.589 ms
(12 rows)
```

Does anyone have any idea what's blocking this query from being on the order of 10 milliseconds? This should logically be instantaneous with the right index defined. It should only require the time to follow links to the leaf value in the B-Tree.

Someone asked:

> What do you get for SELECT * FROM pg_stats WHERE tablename = 'foo' and attname = 'bar_uid';?

```
 schemaname |       tablename        |   attname   | inherited | null_frac | avg_width | n_distinct |                                                                                                        most_common_vals                                                                                                         |                    most_common_freqs                     | histogram_bounds | correlation | most_common_elems | most_common_elem_freqs | elem_count_histogram
------------+------------------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+------------------+-------------+-------------------+------------------------+----------------------
 public     | foo                    | bar_uir     | f         |         0 |        16 |          6 | {fa61424d-389f-4e75-ba2d-b77e6bb8491f,5c5dcae9-1b7e-4413-99a1-62fde2b89c32,50b1e842-fc32-4c2c-b00f-4a17c3c1c5fa,7ff1999c-c0ea-b700-343f-9a737f6ad659,f667b353-e199-4890-9ffd-4940ea11fe2c,b24ce968-29fd-4587-ba1f-227036ee3135} | {0.203733,0.203167,0.201567,0.195867,0.1952,0.000466667} |                  |   -0.158093 |                   |                        |
(1 row)
```

Comment: Does it change if you run `vacuum analyze foo`? The estimates in the plan seem foar off. How many unique `bar_uid` values does the table have? One alternative to try would be `select sequential_id from foo where bar_uid = 'fa61424d-389f-4e75-ba2d-b77e6bb8491f' order by sequential_id desc limit 1;` - does that yield a better plan?

Comment: Could you also provide the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)`?

Comment: That plan would only make sense if there are lots of rows with `bar_uid = 'fa61424d-389f-4e75-ba2d-b77e6bb8491f'`. What do you get for `SELECT * FROM pg_stats WHERE tablename = 'foo' and attname = 'bar_uid';`?

Comment: Please also have a look at the cost, not only at your current execution times. The planner is totally correct with the first plan, although it was a tiny bit slower in your current data set but if growing will certainly be much better than with additional grouping. Please enable `track_io_timing` so that you can see actual I/O time within an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` (with another UUID filter value).

Comment: Added the result of the 2nd query with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`

Comment: > That plan would only make sense if there are lots of rows with bar_uid = 'fa61424d-389f-4e75-ba2d-b77e6bb8491f'. 

Yep, there are a lot of rows when `bar_uid` takes on this value. There are about 300,000. However, I don't understand why it would take 200-300ms with an index should allow for nearly instant access of the MAX value.

Comment: > What do you get for SELECT * FROM pg_stats WHERE tablename = 'foo' and attname = 'bar_uid';?

I'll add this to the post

Comment: Must be something in your environment. I tried with 9.6.12 and 11.2 with 1.5 million rows (300000 for that bar_id), and I always get this plan: https://explain.depesz.com/s/NaEy essentially an `Index Only Scan Backward` with just 4 heap fetches (less than 1ms)